# Merge/Push associative array into each row of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I need to merge an associative array into each row of a 2d array.

The first array is:

```
[
    ["supply_id" => 2],
    ["supply_id" => 4],
    ["supply_id" => 5],
]
```

The second array is:

```
["status" => 1, "t1_id" => 59]
```

The result I need is:

```
[
    ["supply_id" => 2, "status" => 1, "t1_id" => 59],
    ["supply_id" => 4, "status" => 1, "t1_id" => 59],
    ["supply_id" => 5, "status" => 1, "t1_id" => 59],
]
```

How can I push the associative array elements into each row?

Comment: if it's always the same, why do you want to merge them? It doesn't make a lot of sense and if you have a lot of elements in your first array it could cause memory issues if a lot of users are running this script.

Comment: @FMashiro I am agree with you regarding memory issues, But I get many inputs from Muliple selection dropdown and insert it to table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through first array then merge values in new array:

```
$array_1= array
(
    0 => array
        (
            "supply_id" => 2
        ),

    1 => array
        (
            "supply_id" => 4
        ),

    2 => array
        (
            "supply_id" => 5
        ),

);

$array_2=array
(
    "status" => 1,
    "t1_id" => 59
);
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array_1 as $key => $value) {
    $new_array[] = array_merge($value,$array_2);
}
var_dump($new_array);
```

o/p:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'supply_id' => int 2
      'status' => int 1
      't1_id' => int 59
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'supply_id' => int 4
      'status' => int 1
      't1_id' => int 59
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'supply_id' => int 5
      'status' => int 1
      't1_id' => int 59
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:

```
$res = array();
foreach($secondArray as $k => $v){
    $res[$k] = array_merge($secondArray[$k], $firstArray[$k]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we are using simple `foreach` loop for achieving desired output.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/819871)

```
foreach($firstArray as $key  => &$value)
{
    $value=  array_merge($value,$secondArray);
}
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_walk()` or `array_map()` are native functions which are well suited for the task of merging row data with a static array.

`array_map()` will iterate over the rows of the first array and merge each row with the unchanging second array data.  The native function will return a new indexed array of associative rows.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZM6h4))

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($row) => $row += $array2,
        $array1
    )
);
```

---

`array_walk()`'s third input parameter will receive the static value and the third parameter of the callback function will contain the entire passed in array.

The following snippet will modify the first array instead of generating a new result array. `$i` represents the first level keys/indexes which relate to each row -- the `$i` values are not used.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/00qOS))

```
array_walk(
    $array1,
    fn(&$row, $i, $new) => $row += $new,
    $array2
);
var_export($array1);
```